# Best possible Data Structure

Tags: xml, data-structures

I want to convert some XML message into FIX message type.
It involves mapping xml tags to fix tags + for every possible value of XML tag there is appropriate FIX value available.

what data structure will be most effective ?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a Map (Dictionary) to me. Or two actually, one for XML tag -> FIX msg type and one for XML value -> FIX value.

Comment: hash tables will do..bt that involves two hash table lookups.. so just out of curiosity wanted to know if there is anything in which only on lookup will be required .. /

Comment: given that the set of possible values is reasonably sized, the combination of tag/value could give you the msgType/value directly

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary is probably the way to go as Per Norrman has mentioned. A Dictionary is a glorified hash table, which is by far the most efficient data structure that can be used to associate values.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table <--- For a more in depth explanation of why they are very efficient.

Comment: hash tables will do..bt that involves two hash table lookups.. so just out of curiosity wanted to know if there is anything in which only on lookup will be required ..